# Why don't i get ExtJs message box with this code?

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
Ext.application({ 
    name: 'HelloExt', 
    launch: function() { 
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('title', 'msg', Ext.emptyFn); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: are you sure that you put in on the right place...
your code works for me..

Comment: yes, for sure. i' just learning ext but every time i used ext message box, i always fail. #pusing

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error message? My first guess would be that you're using dynamic loading and you haven't loaded the MessageBox before using it:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    requires: ['Ext.window.MessageBox'],
    launch: function() {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('title', 'msg', Ext.emptyFn);
    }
});
```